# Jruby with sevenzipjbinding

Tags: ruby, jruby, 7zip

http://sevenzipjbind.sourceforge.net/basic_snippets.html - Java code example
http://sevenzipjbind.sourceforge.net/javadoc/index.html - api doc

```rb
require "./sevenzipjbinding-AllPlatforms.jar"
require "./sevenzipjbinding.jar"

java_import "net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.ExtractAskMode"
java_import "net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.ExtractOperationResult"
java_import "net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.IArchiveExtractCallback"
java_import "net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.ISequentialOutStream"
java_import "net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.ISevenZipInArchive"
java_import "net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.PropID"
java_import "net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.SevenZip"
java_import "net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.SevenZipException"
java_import "net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.impl.RandomAccessFileInStream"

randomAccessFile = java.io.RandomAccessFile.new(ARGV[0], "r")
SevenZip.initSevenZipFromPlatformJAR
inArchive = SevenZip.openInArchive(nil, RandomAccessFileInStream.new(randomAccessFile))

(0..inArchive.getNumberOfItems-1).each { |i|
    puts
    puts "PATH: #{inArchive.getProperty(i, PropID::PATH)}" # show file name
    puts "SIZE: #{inArchive.getProperty(i, PropID::SIZE)}" # and file size
}

inArchive.close
randomAccessFile.close
```

OK it works in general. But I can't understand extraction.

```java
inArchive.extractSlow(int index, ISequentialOutStream outStream, java.lang.String password)
```

How does ISequentialOutStream work and how get the archived file as string in memory or save it to disk?

Answer (score 0):

[ISequentialOutStream](http://sevenzipjbind.sourceforge.net/javadoc/net/sf/sevenzipjbinding/ISequentialOutStream.html) is an interface defined by the library you are using. It has one method: `write` that takes an array of bytes and returns the number of bytes actually written.

It's up to you how your application should "write" data. If you assume that unpacked data is UTF-8 strings, one way of doing this would be:

```
class MyOutput
  def initialize
    @buffer = java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.new
  end

  def write(bytes)
    @buffer.write(bytes)
  end

  def to_s
    @buffer.toString("UTF-8")
  end
end

output = MyOutput.new
inArchive.extractSlow(index, output, password)
puts output.to_s
```

There's nothing really JRuby-specific about your question - this is just normal Java.

Comment: Thank you for help. One correction.  

`net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.SevenZipException: Implementation of 'int ISequentialOutStream.write(byte[])' should write at least one byte. Returned amount of written bytes: 0`

We need '@buffer.size' in 'write' method.  

`def write(bytes)
  @buffer.write(bytes)
  return @buffer.size
end`

Comment: Good catch, but I think you need to return `bytes.length`. The JavaDoc is not totally clear, but usually you tell the caller how much you were able to write *of what they gave you*.